# cldoc crashes on template partial specialization

Tags: c++, documentation, cldoc

This question was flagged as unclear what I'm asking.  For clarity, I am asking for a workaround to get this document generator working properly against my codebase.  (perhaps splitting the job into batches?  Is that possible with cldocs?  Perhaps issuing different command line options?  Perhaps my invocation is wrong or misguided?)

I have filed a bug against the project that you can find here with some additional information about my environment (including a full command line located here: http://pastebin.com/JxWf9hRB).

https://github.com/jessevdk/cldoc/issues/73

Original Question:

I'm investigating using cldocs for automated documentation.  However, it's crashing on my codebase, with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/cldoc", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('cldoc==1.6', 'console_scripts', 'cldoc')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cldoc/__init__.py", line 57, in run
    run_generate(rest)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cldoc/__init__.py", line 27, in run_generate
    cmdgenerate.run(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cldoc/cmdgenerate.py", line 151, in run
    run_generate(t, opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cldoc/cmdgenerate.py", line 33, in run_generate
    generator.generate(xmlout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cldoc/generators/xml.py", line 55, in generate
    Generator.generate(self, outdir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cldoc/generators/generator.py", line 22, in generate
    self.generate_node(node)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cldoc/generators/xml.py", line 543, in generate_node
    self.generate_page(node)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cldoc/generators/xml.py", line 510, in generate_page
    elem = self.node_to_xml(node)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cldoc/generators/xml.py", line 496, in node_to_xml
    chelem = self.node_to_xml(child)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cldoc/generators/xml.py", line 485, in node_to_xml
    self.call_type_specific(node, elem, 'to_xml')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cldoc/generators/xml.py", line 465, in call_type_specific
    getattr(self, nm)(node, elem)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cldoc/generators/xml.py", line 273, in method_to_xml
    if len(node.override) > 0:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cldoc/nodes/method.py", line 43, in override
    bases = list(self.parent.bases)
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'bases'
```

EDIT:

After a long while, I have been able to pare it down to a minimal example.

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo {
  int baz(T const& t) const { }
};

template<typename T, int N>
class Bar { };

template<typename T, int N>
struct Foo<Bar<T, N>> {
  int baz(Bar<T, N> const& a) const;
};

template<typename T, int N>
int Foo<Bar<T, N>>::baz(Bar<T, N> const& a) const { }
```

Whereas this works:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo {
  int baz(T const& t) const { }
};

template<typename T, int N>
class Bar { };

template<typename T, int N>
struct Foo<Bar<T, N>> {
  int baz(Bar<T, N> const& a) const { }
};
```

Comment: can you split the command into several other shorter ones? I'm thinking  the command line buffer might overflow -hence your problems

Comment: @Pandrei, I was wrong about the issue being length. The issue seems to be certain structures which are not handled properly by the parser.  I've included a minimal example.

Comment: Out of the blue, some desperate ideas that might be worth trying, just in case: 1) Have you tried separating the brackets, i.e using "> >" instead of ">>" (unlikely to solve the issue considering the working example has some ">>" as well). 2) Have you tried to change the name of template parameter of Foo from "T" to "U"? (there *might* be a name-clash bug of the parser between the two "T" that you use locally for different things).

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I just saw that your bug entry has an answer stating what the bug of cldoc is (different than what I suggested).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `cldoc` relies on clang in parsing the sources, it requires proper C/C++ flags (e.g. `-std=c++11`) to operate properly.

Then, even with proper flags it explodes on certain constructions which look valid. Particularly it attempts to process out of template class method definitions with a seemingly wrong context. Particularly the problem with the `Foo<Bar<T, N>>::baz()` definition is that during processing its `self.parent` is equal to `Root` or `Namespace` objects (which obviously don't have "bases" attribute and shouldn't have), not `Class` or alike object, for which `bases` are used to track down overrides list for a particular method.

I've prepared a workaround for the problem which simply "relaxes" manipulations with `self.parent` attributes at the point of explosion and have posted it as a comment to the issue. But certainly it's not the solution. Perhaps a proper solution should first decide if such out-of-class method definitions have to be processed this way at all, probably a correct way is to handle overrides list at methods *declarations* only.

Here's the patch:

```
diff --git a/cldoc/nodes/method.py b/cldoc/nodes/method.py
index f910241..3e1208f 100644
--- a/cldoc/nodes/method.py
+++ b/cldoc/nodes/method.py
@@ -40,7 +40,7 @@ class Method(Function):
             return self._override

         # Lookup in bases, recursively
-        bases = list(self.parent.bases)
+        bases = list(getattr(self.parent, "bases", []))
         mname = self.name

         self._override = []
```

Comment: oh weird.  It works if the extension is .cc or .cpp and not if the extension is .h or .hpp  Unfortunately, the file I originally pared the test example from is a .hpp file.

Comment: I've commented the bug in the issue page on Github and provided a patch to workaround the problem.

Comment: If you post this as an answer i will vote it up, accept it, and if possible relaunch a bounty and assign it to you.

Comment: Just relaunched one. Can award in 24 hours.

Comment: What should I do to win the bounty? I'm pretty new to the SO, and this is the first time I'm getting an award after it has been expired.

Comment: You don't have to do anything. Either I award it manually, or the system awards it automatically if your answer is the highest upvoted, with a score of at least 2 or accepted.